# "ORA-22814: attribute or element value is larger than specified in type" error in export to 11.2 format

Tags: oracle, datapump

System Patch Level:

1. 28790651;OJVM RELEASE UPDATE: 12.2.0.1.190115 (28790651)
2. 28870605;OCW JAN 2019 RELEASE UPDATE 12.2.0.1.190115 (28870605)
3. 28822515;Database Jan 2019 Release Update : 12.2.0.1.190115 (28822515)

expdp system@pdb1 TABLES=tbl VERSION=11.2 DIRECTORY=dmp DUMPFILE=test.dmp LOGFILE=test.log

Oracle triggers the following error.

> ORA-39126: Worker unexpected fatal error in
> KUPW$WORKER.FETCH_XML_OBJECTS [ORA-22814: attribute or element value
> is larger than specified in type

For detailed information, I have changed errorstack level before export.

> alter system set events='22814 trace name errorstack level 3';

and I get the following error in logfile.

> ORA-22814: attribute or element value is larger than specified in type
> ----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=duvyz0kwp8zxp) -----
> SELECT /*+all_rows*/ SYS_XMLGEN(VALUE(KU$), XMLFORMAT.createFormat2('T_STAT_T', '7')), 0 ,KU$.BASE_OBJ.NAME ,KU$.BASE_OBJ.OWNER_NAME ,KU$.BASE_OBJ.TYPE_NAME ,'TABLE_STATISTICS' FROM SYS.KU$_11_2_TAB_STATS_VIEW KU$ WHERE NOT BITAND(KU$.BASE_OBJ.FLAGS,128)!=0 AND   KU$.OBJ_NUM IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_METADATA.FETCH_OBJNUMS)) AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  SYS.KU$NOEXP_TAB A WHERE A.OBJ_TYPE='TABLE' AND A.NAME=KU$.BASE_OBJ.NAME AND A.SCHEMA=KU$.BASE_OBJ.OWNER_NAME) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  SYS.KU$NOEXP_TAB A WHERE A.OBJ_TYPE='SCHEMA' AND A.NAME=KU$.BASE_OBJ.OWNER_NAME)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Support document ID 1055332.1 (Full Data Pump Export Fails with ORA-39125 ORA-22814) suggests that you should recreate data pump objects by following certain steps. Which steps? They are described in there; have a look.

Comment: I followed document you sent, and executed catproc.sql and dbload.sql, finally utlrp.sql. Error is not resolved.

Comment: Raise a service request on My Oracle Support and see what they say about it.